# Merge 2 associative arrays in one without breaking the structure

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, array-merge

I've this array:

```
$request = array(
    'method' => 'Document.create',
    'params' => Array (

        'document' => Array ( SOME DATA

            ),

        'thirdaddress' => Array ( SOME DATA

            ),
        'row' => Array (

            '1' => Array ( SOME DATA
            ),

            '2' => Array ( SOME DATA

            ),

            '4' => Array ( SOME DATA
            ),

        )
    )
);
```

I want to "inject" this **between '2' and '4' keys:**

```
'3' => Array (    SOME DATA

                ),
```

I figure to inject the with the same structure  like that:

```
$secondArray = array(
        'params'=>Array(
            'row'=> Array(
                '3' => Array (    SOME DATA

                ),
            )   
        )       
    );
```

I tried this: 
 1. `$request['params']['row']['3']=$secondArray;` 
 2. `$request = array_merge($request,$secondArray);` 
 3. `$request = array_merge_recursive($request,$secondArray);`

ksort don't work too.. My row is stuck as the last place ..
i've done a

`if(STATEMENT){
        //$request = array_merge_recursive($request,$secondArray;
        //$request['params']['row']['3']=$secondArray['params']['row']['3'];
        $request['params']['row']['3']=$secondArray;
        ksort($request);
    }
    die(dump($request));`

Where am I wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: `$request['params']['row']['3']= array(SOME DATA)`?

Comment: Not really the best solution but will do the work: `$request['params']['row']['3'] = $secondArray['params']['row']['3'];` based on Jon's idea.

Comment: @Bobby this code puts the '3' at the end of array :/

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the edit. Ok, now my code is not valid anymore XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simply inserting it, this should work -

```
$request['params']['row']['3']  = Array(SOME DATA);
//This sorts the "row" keys - 
ksort($request['params']['row'], SORT_NUMERIC)
```

Comment: this code inserts yes , but at the wrong place , i need the '3' between the '2' and '4'

Comment: @Azrael_404 You can use ksort() with sort_flag as SORT_NUMERIC. Check the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try [array_merge_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php):

```
<?php
$request = array(
    'method' => 'Document.create',
    'params' => Array (

        'document' => Array ( SOME DATA

            ),

        'thirdaddress' => Array ( SOME DATA

            ),
        'row' => Array (

            '1' => Array ( SOME DATA
            ),

            '2' => Array ( SOME DATA

            ),

            '4' => Array ( SOME DATA
            ),

        )
    )
);

$secondArray = array(
    'params'=>Array(
        'row'=> Array(
            '3' => Array ('foo' => 'bar'),
        )   
    )       
);

$request = array_merge_recursive($request, $secondArray)
```

Comment: The recursive puts the '3' at the end of the $request , not between '2' and '4' keys

Comment: You cannot directly inject the '3' key between '2' and '4' keys. Instead you will have to inject it the way I suggested and then manually sort the resulting $request['params']['row'] array using ksort() for example.

Comment: Try ksort($request['params']['row'])

Answer (score 0):

With point 1. you are nearly good, you just need this change.
Instead of:

```
$secondArray = array(
    'params'=>Array(
        'row'=> Array(
            '3' => Array (    SOME DATA

            ),
        )   
    )       
);
```

Try this:

```
$secondArray = array(SOME DATA);
```

Comment: Like the rest it puts the array at the end of $request

Comment: Add ksort($request['params']['row']); then. It sorts by key so that's exactly what you want.